# Add a view/activity on top of a ListView [Android]

Tags: android, listview, subview

I want to have a view with several choices when I click an element of my ListView. I was thinking of implementing an AlertDialog but as I need more than 3 options it is not possible...
I also thought of putting my ListView in a FrameLayout and have an view with a gone visibility that I would turn visible at the click and update the content but I don't know If it's a good idea.
I could do with some advice,

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Or something like this article ? http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ContextMenu, if dialog works fine for you. If you don't want the dialog then use [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html).

Comment: Actually, popupwindow suits best the level of customization of what I intended. but contextmenu would have worked for a lower level. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html)

[This tutorial](http://www.mikeplate.com/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/) may help.

Edit based on the comment:

Hmmm.. Since you want more than 3 options and icons in the menu that's displayed when a item is clicked; you could set an onclicklistener for an item in the list and on clicking switch to  an Activity that extends a BaseAdapter along with your own custom layout.

I personally don't recommend this as it could complicate things quite a bit. Context menu is quite straightforward and way to go.

Comment: Yeah I tested that too but I was annoyed by the "no icon" of this type of menu...

Answer (score 0):

You can create another activity, and give it the dialog theme:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

This causes it to look like an AlertDialog, but you have full control over what it looks like.

Note that when I used this previously it was rather slow, at least in the emulator though.

Comment: I'm trying the popupWindow and if i can't get what I want, I'll go for your idea.
I'm also thinking of getting the source code of the option menu and see what I can do with it.
thx